# Difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: browser

Is that true or do I have some problems with the adaptation of the website? The icons on my website are rounded while I'm browsing it through Firefox, but they are completely square in Chrome.

Are there any problems with those browsers or is it a problem with my website(https://houseweather.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

Different browsers render webpages differently. It "shouldn't be" but it is "normal" behavior...  well depending on the code you use for your web site. You should make sure to use the appropriate web site coding techniques (e.g. define CSS styles) in order to minimize the differences.

There are tons of webpages about this topic for novices, intermediates and experts... just google e.g. "differences browsers website rendering comparison".

However, for detailed questions, I would advise you to go to the appropriate StackExchange site. SU is not the right site one to post web coding questions.